# How to set readonly property to false on multiple textboxes with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have the following three controls which all have same class named "txt11" and I want to change the readonly property of all three textboxes to false whenever
I click edit button.

```js
$(".btn11").click(function(){
  $(".txt11").focus();
  $(".txt11").prop("readonly", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="database" class="txt11">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="sql" class="txt11">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="mysql" class="txt11">
<input type="button" value="Edit" name="btnEdit11"id="btnXyz2" class="btn11"/>
```

The reason why I am using same class is that I am rendering these input boxes dynamically at run time so I am not sure how many textboxes will be rendered.

But only the last textbox is being set to `readonly=false` the above input boxes are still set readonly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem come from the focus `$(".txt11").focus();` that will focus the last occurrence that have the class `txt11`, so you should specify the one you want to focus, e.g :

```
$(".txt11:eq(0)").focus(); //Focusing the first input
```

The `prop` by class will assign the attribute to all inputs.

**NOTE :** you can't focus the `readonly` fields, so you should add the focus statement after setting the `readonly` to `false`.

```js
$(".btn11").click(function(){
    $(".txt11").prop("readonly", false);
    $(".txt11:eq(0)").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="database" class="txt11">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="sql" class="txt11">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="mysql" class="txt11">
<input type="button" value="Edit" name="btnEdit11"id="btnXyz2" class="btn11"/>
```

**Focus by group edit :**

```js
var last_class = 'txt11';

$(".btn11").click(function(){
  $(".txt11").prop("readonly", false);
  $(".txt11:eq(0)").focus();
});

$('body').on('focus', "input:text", function(){
  var current_class = $(this).prop('class');

  if( $(this).prop('readonly') ){
    if(current_class!=last_class){
      $("."+last_class).prop("readonly", true);
      $("."+current_class).prop("readonly", false);
    }
  }

  last_class = current_class;
});
```

```css
input[readonly]{
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="database" class="txt10">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="sql" class="txt10">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="mysql" class="txt10">

<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="database" class="txt11">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="sql" class="txt11">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="mysql" class="txt11">

<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="database" class="txt12">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="sql" class="txt12">
<input readonly="" name="txtSkill[]" value="mysql" class="txt12">

<input type="button" value="Edit" name="btnEdit11"id="btnXyz2" class="btn11"/>
```

Comment: You CAN focus after setting the readonly to false as per my answer

Comment: So now it is more or less the same as my anwer - only difference is .eq vs :eq

Comment: Still, I had the focus before you did ;)

Comment: Yes and I made a snippet for OP you had to "improve" :P

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem. But I have one more question suppose I want to set the readonly property to true the moment I focus out of text box. But here the case is that I dont want to loose the writeonly feature until I actually move to different group of textboxes ie I dont leave the class of textboxes with name txt11. But if I move to say txt10 then set all the textboxes with class name txt11 to readonly.

Comment: You could use `blur()` event and check the class, add this to your OP, i'll update my snippet.

Answer (score 3):

FIRST allow input THEN focus - and you can focus only one input.

```js
$(".btn11").on("click", function() {
  $(".txt11").prop("readonly", false) // FIRST readonly=false
    .eq(0).focus(); // THEN focus the first
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly="readonly" name="txtSkill[]" value="database" class="txt11">
<input readonly="readonly" name="txtSkill[]" value="sql" class="txt11">
<input readonly="readonly" name="txtSkill[]" value="mysql" class="txt11">
<input type="button" value="Edit" name="btnEdit11" id="btnXyz2" class="btn11" />
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem. But I have one more question suppose I want to set the readonly property to true the moment I focus out of text box. But here the case is that I dont want to loose the writeonly feature until I actually move to different group of textboxes ie I dont leave the class of textboxes with name **txt11**. But if I move to say **txt10** then set all the textboxes with class name **txt11** to readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamkarthik08/Lvvcd/427/) works for your solution

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" value="123" class="test" id="test"  /><br />
<input class="test" readonly="true" type="text" value="123" />
<buton id="editClick">
 Edit
</button>

$("#editClick").on('click', function(){
   $('.test').attr('readonly', false);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

On click of the button or the event you required use the following jquery code

```
$(".classname").prop("readonly", false);
```